# Azure Active Directory get current signed in users

Tags: active-directory, azure-active-directory

Using c# - I would like to get a list of current signed in users to my AAD or to check each user's status by submitting userID and getting true/false for its signed-in status. is this possible?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can't exactly get current signed-in user status by submitting userID. You can use get [Sign-in activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/reports-monitoring/concept-sign-ins) reports in the Azure Active Directory portal which will give complete information of user including his login time.

We can also use [MS Graph query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/signin-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) to get the information which we can use it in our programming implementations.